# How can I get access_token from auth-module, Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, nuxt.js

I try to build Facebook login with auth-module the link below with Nuxt.js.

https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module

I can not get "access_token". the code is follows.

```
// pages/login.vue
export default {
   methods: {
       this.$auth.loginWith('facebook')
   }
}
```

the call back URI is like this.

```
https://localhost:3000/facebook/oauth_callback/?#access_token=***&data_access_expiration_time=1561715202&expires_in=4398&reauthorize_required_in=7776000&state=MC4xOTU3MDM2ODIxMzIzOTA5OA
```

```
// pages/facebook/oauth_callback/index.vue
<template>
  <section>
    <p>{{ this.$auth.$state }}</p>
    <p>{{ this.$route.query }}</p
  </section>
</template>
```

this.$auth.$state don't include "access_token". How can I get "access_token"?
I don't also understand why the URI include "#" in get parameter field. because of it, I can't get access_token from "this.$route.query".

Answer (score 31):

Finally, I can do this with following code.

```
this.$auth.getToken('facebook')
```

Thanks for watching it guys.

Comment: Thank you for this useful question.
How can I use this in server side ?
when i use this code in `asyncData` it return `undefined`

Comment: Try this code. Probably you can use this. asyncData({ app }) { app.$auth.getToken('facebook') }

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
this.$auth.strategy.token.get()
```

Source: [github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/740)

It may only be for the [dev](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/) release.